# GCC: symbols loaded, but function names are "??"

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, qemu

I'm compiling a toy OS using `gcc -g` for C files, `nasm -g` for asm files, and `ld` to get everything together.

I run it with `qemu -s`, and start `gdb` with `-x` this:

```
file build/kernel.elf
target remote localhost:1234
```

Inspecting the symbols in the file shows functions and their names:

```
$ nm -g build/kernel.elf
00101000 D framebuffer
0010001d T kstart
00100010 T loader
00103000 B NULL
```

If I set a named breakpoint (e.g. `break kstart`) gdb goes along with it, but when it actually breaks:

```
0x000fd29f in ?? ()
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10001d: file src/kernel.c, line 19.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000fd29f in ?? ()
#1  0x90669066 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Function names are not there anymore? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The debugger might have problems stepping through your assembly if you don't provide certain debugging informations. May that be the case?

Comment: How do I provide whatever information is necessary? I'm already using the `-g` switches, and the symbols show up on inspection, plus I can break on them

Comment: I actually don't recall, but there is something. You might want to consider changing your user name so people can easily use the @username syntax to refer to your name.

Comment: the parameter to obtain the max gdb information withing the .o file is -gdb3  then the file will contain line number, symbol names, function names, and much more. suggest you read up on the gcc and gdb utilities

Comment: Possibly corrupted stack? Or do you have a function at 0xfd29f?

Comment: No. Sounds like that's the problem -- but the program works fine, and I can't find anything odd by eye. How could I debug that?